# when using constraints in ios autolayout, are there benefits to shorter constraint chains?

Tags: ios, autolayout

For example, when I want to make the leading value of 10 different UI elements match, should I be constraining 9 of them to the first item's leading value, or should I create a chain 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 ...etc.

I was wondering about the performance differences and whether I should prefer one for maintenance reasons.

Comment: Watch  this WWDC video. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/220/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to answer an abstract question.

If you want the leading of 10 UI elements to match...

First, you're almost certainly better off putting them in a `UIStackView`... you constrain the stack view's leading and you're done.

Second, if there is a reason you don't want to (or can't) use a stack view, then the answer depends on what else you might be doing.

Suppose you want element 3 "indented" 40-pts?

- If they're all aligned to element 1, you only change the constant of element 3.
- If they're "chained" you have to change the constants of elements 3 and 4.

Suppose you want elements 5 through 10 "indented" 40-pts?

- If they're all aligned to element 1, you have to change the constants of elements 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.
- If they're "chained" you only change the constant of element 5.

Suppose you want to "insert" an element between 3 and 4? Or remove element 6?

Suppose any of the above - or any number of other possibilities - are "conditional" and factor into the alignment?

As you can see, the **preference** of one over the other will depend on many things.

Comment: I see. I guess I was mainly worried about the performance considerations or whether I would break something by choosing one over the other. Best choice is to go for a stack view but sometimes I have trouble getting the stack view to do what I want

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet - stack views have made many aspects of layout so easy, it almost feels like "cheating" to me. Once you've experimented with them for a while, you'll wonder how you could live without them.